# Jenkins not getting launched after docker start

Tags: docker, jenkins

I started my Jenkins Docker image that I had saved earlier.

```
docker start -ai <my_container_ID>
```

I can see that jenkins has started in console but it doesn't get launched: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zMfJ.png)

For the first time, I had started it using docker run command after which Jenkins got launched on browser and I also added some jobs in it and did docker commit.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can we see the full docker run command? Also, are you using the new image created by the docker commit command?

Comment: I created a new image by using docker commit command. Here's the command that I am using to start the new docker image:   docker start -ai 6fdc8f8b76c3

Comment: When docker commit creates a new image, for you to use it you need to create a new container based on that by executing docker run not docker start. docker start is for starting a stopped container.

Comment: After doing docker commit, I killed the process using docker kill <container> and then started the new image with docker start

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. My bad! I was killing the container after I stopped it. And that's why everytime I used the docker start command it was starting the tool from scratch. 
The correct way to start your container from where you left it is that you stop the container and then start it. 
**docker stop <container_id> followed by docker start <container_id>**

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I see that you started a new container from jenkins image, made some changes and then did docker commit for creating a new image based on that.

In order to run a new container from that image you need to use docker run using the image's hash return by the docker commit command. Example:

```
$ docker commit cc79f8ec407d #hash of the container you want to commit
sha256:227efd2e30a9033e6ce288084c6452aa5a5112974ea833b559429a9ae78697a8 # new image hash return by docker commit
$ docker run 227efd2e30a9033e6ce288084c6452aa5a5112974ea833b559429a9ae78697a8 # hash of the new image
```

But bare in mind that when you run this new container from that image jenkins might not consider it as a new installation because the initialization process was already done before the commiting.

Comment: I tried this but it gives the log that I had attached with the question. Jenkins doesn't get launched on browser.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to just point your browser to the IP address of your new Virtual Machine Docker host.

You could monkey around with ifconfig or ipconfig to figure it out, but thankfully Docker Toolbox comes with a handy command line option by utilizing docker-machine:

`docker-machine ip default`

That’s the IP of your host and where your web services will be listening! Granted this IP is on your local machine and not externally reachable. If you want outside services to hit your machine, you’ll need to set up port forwarding.

Now try   `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-master jenkins`

Comment: If I run this command, it again starts the installation from scratch. Asks for initialAdminPassword. I want my container to start from where I last saved it by doing docker commit.

Comment: docker run creates a new container. 
I solved this by stopping and starting the container.